# Object initialization without "new" C++

Tags: c++, oop, syntax, standards

I am wondering a bit about object initialization in C++. I read using the 'new' keyword should be avoided if possible, since I don't need what it offers (dynamic allocation, right?), and I don't want to have to delete the object manually. I am having troubles calling the initialization of my object without using new though. I have this class:

```
class Apodization {

public:
    Apodization()
    {
    std::cout << "Constructor for Apodization" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and this code:

```
Apodization* apoObj();
// Apodization* apoObj = new Apodization();
```

The print happens as expected when using new to create the object, but not without. I'm guessing this is because I'm only creating a pointer of Apodization type in the example above, but I don't know where to go from there. I would like to know the proper way to initialize an Apodization object without using the new keyword. Thanks for the help! I am finding C++ classes a bit weird coming from Java and Python.

Comment: Unless you need a pointer to the object you should just have: `Apodization apoObj();`

Comment: If you have a pointer, nothing is created until you call `new`. If you have a stack-allocated object you'll call the initializer.

Comment: if you want dynamic allocation and do not want to manually delete the object, use std::unique_ptr.

Comment: You might want to consider finding a book, class, or tutorial on C++ to help you get started with the basics (C++ is very much *not* Java).

Comment: @NathanOliver Writing `Apodization apoObj();` declares a function named `apoObj` taking no arguments and returning `Apodization`.  See "most vexing parse" in google.  Either use C++11 brace initialization `Apodization apoObj{};` or omit the parenthesis.

Comment: @legalize ah yes.  I forgot about the most vexing parse

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An Object is initialised without `new` using RAII (Resource Allocation is Initialisation). What this means is that when you declare an instance of Apodization, memory for the instance is **allocated** on the stack and then the constructor is called to set up the **initial** state.

This means that simply writing:

```
int main(){
   Apodization apodization;
   //apodization.doSomething();
   return 0;
}
```

is all you need to get the ball rolling! 
(Being a Java guy myself, I love the succinctness of this!)

As the object is allocated on the stack, the destructor will automatically be called at the end of the scope; no manual memory management required.

P.S. I highly recommend you read [Bjarne Stroustrup C++11 Programming Guide](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html)!

Comment: Awesome thank you! Works great! And I'll definitely check out the programming guide. I could use one for leaning C++

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The `new` operator allocates memory for an object, calls the constructor for that object, and then returns the pointer. In your code, all you are doing is declaring the pointer without any memory being set aside for it, or a constructor doing any work. It is just a pointer to nothing.

Comment: More specifically, it's an *uninitialized pointer* that points to something, but nothing valid.

Comment: The question isn't really about new, but constructor invocation.

Answer (score -1):

Just create a static instance:

```
static Apodization apoObj;  // This will create an instance of the object.
```

If you wish to use a pointer to access it then point to the static instance:

```
static Apodization SapoObj;  // This will create an instance of the object.
static Apodization* apoObj = &SapoObj;
```

Comment: I suppose you have been downvoted because `Apodization apoObj();` is not valid in C++, it has to be `Apodization apoObj;`.

Comment: And because `Apodization* apoObj = &SapoObj;` has no real use and can cause problems if you don't know about how the scope of `SapoObj` affects the pointer `apoObj` if it is used after the scope ends.

Comment: @jpo38 - Thanks - not been doing a lot of C++ lately!

Comment: And why are you trying to make this `static`? Without more context, `static` can mean one of three things depending on the scope and will just add confusion to a beginner.

Comment: `static` at the global scope is just another name for "global variable".  The question is about invoking an object's constructor, not about making global variables.